# update() method gets called/notified in ScoreView class, but does not update the Label

Tags: java, codenameone, observer-pattern

```
public class ScoreView extends Container implements Observer {
private Label livesLabel;
private Label foodLevelLabel;

    public ScoreView() {
        // Create and add labels to the container
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER));
        this.getStyle().getTextDecoration();
    
        this.livesLabel = new Label("Lives: ");
        this.foodLevelLabel = new Label("Food Level: ");
        this.livesLabel.getAllStyles().setFgColor(ColorUtil.BLUE);
        this.foodLevelLabel.getAllStyles().setFgColor(ColorUtil.BLUE);
    
        
        this.add(livesLabel);
        this.add(foodLevelLabel);
    
    }
    
    @Override 
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    
        if (o instanceof GameWorld) {
            GameWorld gw = (GameWorld) o;
            livesLabel.setText("Lives: " + Integer.toString(gw.getChanceToLive()));
            System.out.println("Updated lives label text: " + livesLabel.getText());
            foodLevelLabel.setText("Food Level: " + Integer.toString(gw.getAnt().getFoodLevel()));
            System.out.println("Updated food level label text: " + foodLevelLabel.getText());
           
    
        }
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }

}
```

** The ScoreView class is registered as Observer in another class (Observable). update() method   * get executed. The print statement print the correct label value. I also have revalidate() called * on update() method. Seems like the container does not update new labels. I am stuck at this     * point. Please help!
*

Answer (score 0):

There are three possibilities I can think of. I suggest placing a breakpoint in the debugger and verifying which one of them applies:

- You have more than one instance of the `ScoreView` class. You added one to the UI and another one is in the observer callback
- The text is there but there is no room to show it. You can check this with the component inspector tool
- The event might be sent on a separate thread that isn't the EDT and might have triggered a problem

You only need `revalidate()` a `repaint()` is redundant here.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Yeah, I had exactly two instance of the ScoreView in my controller class. One to the UI and another at the Observer callback. Thanks for the feedback.